# ¿Como puedo dejar fijas las tablas de enrutamiento?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

Tengo un servidor con 2 tarjetas de red (una interna y otra externa con salida a Internet), he configurado la interna para que de direcciones por DHCP a clientes en una red interna y querria que esos clientes tengan a traves de esa tarjeta interna del servidor router salida a Internet.

Por tanto he ejecutado los siguientes comandos en el servidor router:

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.0.0/24 -o ens33 -j MASQUERADE
```

Tras esos comandos los clientes salen a Internet y se ven entre ellos pero tras reiniciar el servidor router pierde la configuracion dada en `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` y la vuelve a dejar a 0 y las tablas de enrutamiento se pierden aunque también instalé el paquete `iptables-persistent` y marqué para que se mantuvieran las configuraciones de iptables tanto en IPv4 como en IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

ip_forward se controloa en el archivo `/etc/sysctl.conf` :

net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1

Para que el comando iptables se mantenga entre reinicios debe cargarse como reglas de pre-inicio de red

Archivo `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables`

```
#!/bin/sh
iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
exit 0
```

Puedes editar y agregar las reglas adicionales en el archivo de reglas iptables (ej: /etc/iptables.rules o como se llame en tu sistema)

Answer (score 0):

Justo después de preguntar he dado con la respuesta. En el fichero /etc/sysctl.conf se deberán descomentar las lineas "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" para IPv4 y "net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1" para IPv6, guardar el fichero y ejecutar el comando "sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf" para que entre a funcionar esas modificaciones realizadas.

Por tanto, como resumen como si alguien lo encuentra necesario para habilitar el enrutamiento en Ubuntu 18.04 / 20.04 se han seguido los siguientes pasos:

.Ejecutar el comando "more /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" para verificar que de un 0 al estar deshabilitado el enrutamiento.
.Ejecutar el comando "echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward".
.Ejecutar el comando "iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT".
.Ejecutar el comando "iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s x.x.x.x -o NIC -j MASQUERADE" siendo x.x.x.x la red interna desde la que se quiere salir a Internet y NIC la tarjeta que tiene salida a Internet del servidor router.
.Instalar el paquete que hace persistentes las tablas de enrutamiento con el comando "apt-get install iptables-persistent" aceptando que guarde las configuraciones IPv4 e IPv6 actuales.
.Opcionalmente volver a guardar las configuraciones de iptables para IPv4 e IPv6 con los comandos "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rule.v4" y "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rule.v6".
.Descomentar las lineas "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" para IPv4 y "net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1" para IPv6, guardar el fichero y ejecutar el comando "sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf" para que esas lineas del fichero /etc/sysctl.conf comiencen a funcionar y tengamos el enrutamiento hacia Internet de una red con equipos con tarjetas de red internas lista.